# use pyodbc to read Microsoft access long binary data

Tags: python, ms-access-2010

I am using pyodbc driver to get long binary data from Microsoft Access i.e. .mdb file. Following is the code snippet and output.

**code:**

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=d:\\testarea\\test.mdb')

sqlcommand = 'select * from FORMULA_GROUP'

result = cur.execute(sqlcommand).fetchall()

result[0][0]
```

---

but I get this string as output

```
b'\x01\x06\xa4w\xae\xd6\xad\xe3\x01\x00\x04\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\x08\x00CFormula\x05\x00\x080G9yHh>d\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc8B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16w\x82x\x8f\x8a\xe4@\x00\x07A\x04S\x06\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\n\x00CDyeAmount\x02\x0cA3302||A3302\x120G;6QAfb||66455C17\n\xd7\xa3=\x01\x00\x03\x80\x02\x0cA3317||A3317\x120G;6Xdh0||151273AE\x17\xd9N?\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

anyone know how to decode it??

Comment: You say you are fetching binary data, and that looks like binary data to me. Why are you asking us to decode it? Is this a question about the code that fetches the data, or about how to convert binary data into a human-readable format?

Comment: This .mdb file is generated by a software called Color iMatch(from X-rite ) .when I edit data property and export it to .mdb file, I expected to get something readable data like 'Prescription: group 1 A4310 1%; group 2 A4410 2%.. '。First I try to use .decode('ascii') to decode this string, but I get error . So I want to know how to convert it to readable string?

Comment: What is the data type of the property?

Comment: Are you sure that `[0][0]` is the right part of the query result to be looking in?

Answer (score 0):

This is properties window:

[image: properties]

So, I expected to get something like **`'A4102 1.66;A4412 0.865;A4414 0.745'`** or some readable string

Comment: Don't use the answer box for anything other than an answer to the question. If you want to add information and pictures you should edit the question.